# Is early entry into mystic theurge still an option?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class

My understanding is that originally spell-like abilities could *not* be used to fulfill prestige class requirements, then spell-like abilities *could* be used to fulfill prestige class requirements, and now spell-like abilities can't again.

So if spell-like abilities don't enable early entry into the prestige class [mystic theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge/) anymore right now, is there any way to enter the class before level 7?

Comment: For reference on anyone not well versed in the subject: spell-likes currently don't count as generic spells for prerequisites, but do count as specific spells for prerequisites. I.e. having a racial spell-like to cast *Darkness* doesn't qualify you for anything that requires being able to cast 1st level spells, but does qualify you for anything that requires being able to cast *Darkness* specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most recent [FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qow) on the subject confirms that spell-like abilities cannot qualify for requirements, unless the spell name is called out explicitly.

### Inner Sea Magic's spellcaster guilds

The [Inner Sea Magic](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mfs?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Magic) has a mechanic for being a member of a **Spellcasting Guild**, like an academy of magic studies, where you do some *quests* for them and gain fame within the academy. Then, you can obtain rewards after obtaining a certain amount of Fame, one of which is the **Eclectic Training** (page 22), which increases your *effective caster level* on a single class by +1, including spells known and able to cast.

> As guild students increase in fame, they gain the
>   following rewards:
>
> **Eclectic Training (5 Fame)**: Guilds often require members to master and train in different subjects. When your Fame score in a guild reaches 5, choose one spellcasting class you have at least 1 level in—you increase your effective caster level in that class (including the **number of spells you know and can cast per day**) by +1, to a maximum caster level equal to your total Hit Dice. Single-classed spellcasters should still pick a class to which this bonus applies, since this bonus is retroactive.

The mechanics, as written, expect a character to gain at least 4 fame per character level, which means that by level 2, you already have **+1 caster level** from training with an academy of magic. This benefit cannot increase your caster level to higher than your HD, so the benefit is pretty much exclusive to multiclass characters.

Example: A cleric 1/wizard 1 will cast spells either as cleric 2/wizard 1, or cleric 1/wizard 2.

The system also allows you to become member of more than one guild, as long as you can pay for the *Entrance Fee*, pass the necessary tests and keep up with the *Education Exams*. The book presents us four guilds:

- **Kintargo Opera House** (Cheliax)

  - Entrance Fee 500 gp
  - Entrance Exam DC 17 Perform (sing) check
- **Oenopion Fleshforges** (Nex)

  - Entrance Fee 200 gp
  - Entrance Exam DC 15 Craft (alchemy) check
- **Poisoner’s Guild** (River Kingdoms)

  - Entrance Fee 500 gp
  - Entrance Exam DC 20 Craft (alchemy) check
- **White Grotto** (Absalom)

  - Entrance Fee 50 gp
  - Entrance Exam DC 15 Perform (any) check

At 35+ Fame with a spellcasting guild, you also gain another ability called **Esoteric Training**, which not only increases the previous bonus to +3, but you also gain +1 effective caster level on a second spellcasting class:

> **Esoteric Training (35 Fame)**: The bonus to caster level
>   you gain from Eclectic Training increases to +3 (but is still
>   limited by your total Hit Dice). You may select a second
>   spellcasting class to gain a +1 bonus to effective
>   caster level.

The way to increase your Fame score is to pass periodic (between 3 to 6 months) *Education Checks*, normally 3 to 5 skill checks using a DC of 15 + your ranks on that skill, and pay an additional fee for the new *semester*. Each check increases your Fame by +1. But you also could do extracurricular jobs and requests for the guild and gain Fame points from it.

Just be careful to not get *expelled* from your guilds, or the GM could revoke some of the rewards gained. You may quit by notifying your superior and keep your rewards, but you will no longer be able to acquire new rewards.

Note that those academies are not legal on *Pathfinder Society*, as PFS characters have different guilds they have filiation with, and different boons and rewards that change every season.

Comment: Can you gain that boon more than once, for example choosing each of cleric and wizard so that a 2nd-level cleric/2nd-level wizard with eclectic training in each qualifies for mystic theurge?

Comment: @KRyan i was checking the book, but that would require you to work with two different guilds to work, which is allowed aswell. You just might have to check the filiation conditions to see if you can handle both, but doesn't sound complicated.

Comment: Maybe *boon* is not the proper word, as that is used both on PFS and the Fame System (Ultimate Campaign) as rewards that you can buy with Prestige Points. I will fix it.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the esoteric training option in the same book, which offers 3 levels of one class and 1 level of another (at 35 fame). Having both eclectic and esoteric training would make a mystic theurge a vastly superior option than it otherwise is, even if you cannot get either more than once.

Comment: Yea but 35 Fame is difficult before level 7. In fact, you might obtain that much fame by level 6 or 7, unless the campaign is really slow and you have enough time (more than one year) to take several Education Tests, as you gain +1 Fame every time you pass a test or make an extracurricular activity or task for your guild.

Comment: Sure, but as a commentary for someone considering mystic theurge, a single eclectic training alone is not sufficient to make it worth it. But knowing that you’ll be able to recoup some of those losses as early as 6th or 7th (as a 1st- or 2nd-level mystic theurge) changes that calculus. Seems like a worthy thing to include in an answer.

Comment: I see your point, its worth mentioning because given enough Fame, you can recover the caster level lost on the multiclassing.

Answer (score 8):

## Equipment Trick (sunrod)

Source: Pathfinder Society Field Guide
PFS Legal: Yes

Prerequisite: BAB +1

> **Like the Sun**: You can use a sunrod as an additional material component for any spell that bears the light descriptor.  The spell is treated as one spell level higher (to a maximum of 9th level) for all purposes, including the calculation of saving throw DCs and its ability to overcome sources of magical darkness.

**You can now qualify at level 4.**
Level 1: wizard/witch/sorcerer 1 (make sure you can cast *dancing lantern*)
Level 2: cleric/oracle/shaman 1 (make sure you can cast *dancing lantern*)
Level 3: either one you want, or any class that gives you a +1 BAB and at least 2 skill ranks
Level 4: mystic theurge 1

Comment: The feat is PFS legal or using it as prereq is PFS legal?  (Not that I'm playing PFS, but if you have a link...)

Comment: The feat is legal, I'd be amazed if any PFS GM let you use it satisfy spellcasting prereqs though. It's definitely not RAI and if you wanted to be super-RAW about it I'd respond that as it raises the spell level "for all purposes" you'd need to prepare it/cast it using a higher level slot.

Comment: The main requirement for mystic theurge is being able to cast 2nd level spells. This makes you treat the spell as if it was 2nd, but you still cannot cast 2nd level spells.  If you treat the spel *for all purposes*, then it should also cost you a 2nd level slot.

Comment: @ShadowKras No, actually. Because by the time the sunrod is used up as a material component to a spell, the spell slot has already been used. It turns into a 2nd-level spell only after. This is valid, RAW. Unlikely to fly anywhere though.

Comment: @KRyan wouldn't accepting that also open precedence to using scrolls to cast 2nd level spells and qualify as soon as 4th level regardless of class (UMD)?

Comment: @ShadowKras That’s a good point—yes it would. But ultimately, that’s... RAW for you? The requirement, after all, only says “able” to do something. No stipulations on the circumstances under which you are able to perform that thing, or even if you ever do it. Which is dumb, but it’s still a valid answer even if it’s not nearly as useful as yours.

Comment: @ShadowKras Using a scroll is not casting a spell, it's activating a spell-completion item. Completely different.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet well, if casting from a scroll isn't good enough, casting from a wand is. "Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so **casting a spell from a wand** [takes time]". Very explicitly, a wand-user is casting the spell.

Comment: I ended up accepting the other answer, because I think it is more accepted.  I liked this answer because it is not limited to a campaign.  If only I could accept both!  Now to convince my GM that this is RAW...